# In debug, when the app is frozen, how to know where the main thread is blocked?

Tags: delphi

When I debug, sometimes my app start to freeze for unknown reason. How can I know where in my code the main thread is blocked?

I try to pause the app but then I can only access the CPU view that does not help me.

Comment: Do you mean "blocked" like in "stuck in an infinite loop" (full single-thread CPU usage) or "stuck waiting for a shared resource" (zero CPU usage)?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I don't know :( I just know that the GUI is frozen for unlimited time and I would like to known where the main thread is blocked

Comment: Open the thread list, find the main thread, and double click it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pause, you can view the Call Stack window by opening it at View -> Debug Windows -> Call Stack.

The list will show where you are at the top, and all of the key calls that got you there below it.

[image: Call Stack]

If you are stuck in the CPU code, and want to see why, follow the list down until you get to some aspect of your program or the libraries and find a good place to put a breakpoint so you can step through the next run. You can get the file to open by double clicking on any of the items in the list that have a blue button. Grey circles usually end up in compiled code that means little to the beginner.

Comment: Just make sure to look at the right call stack, the one belonging to the GUI thread.

Comment: That would be true - the thread is important, the problem could be because of a different thread, especially in a deadlock or some mutex blocking the software from progressing, but the main thread is the one you would begin debugging if you had no idea where to begin as above. It is generally the one at the top of the threads window and opened by the first view of a call stack at pause. It is a great place to start learning debugging as a beginner, so that is where I would have OP begin.